# relation does not exist when launch my DJANGO APP in heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm doing an APP with django and I have a problem when I'm deploying it, on heroku PaaS.

The problem is when I launch the app, I see the following error in my url:`relation "calculadora_universidad" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ad"."id", "calculadora_universidad"."nombre" FROM "calculado...`

exactly when try to access in universidad in the html template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
  <h2>Utiliza la calculadora</h2>
        <!--         Calculadora        -->  
      <p><label for="basic-url">1. A que universidad y a que carrera quieres acceder?</label></p>

      <form>
      <select value ="Universidades" name="selectuniversidades" id="selectuniversidades" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"> 
        {% for e in universidades %}
          <option value="{{e.id}}">{{ e.nombre }}</option>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </select><br><br>
      </form>
```

This is because the tables of the models is not created, but I'm following all steps that the heroku center explains, and the last I have try is doing is put the postgres credenteials in my settings and try to migrate but I see the same problem.

When I build the app following this steps: heroku link and I run the comand :
`heroku run python manage.py migrate` (because the syncdb not work now) I don't see the creations of the table how I saw in the local deployment.

I don't know why pass this, somebody know it?

If is usefull, this is my models:

```
class Universidad(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.nombre) 

class Carrera(models.Model):
    universidad = models.ForeignKey(Universidad)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notaCorte = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=5)


def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s %f" % (self.universidad, self.nombre, self.notaCorte)
```

and my views:

```
def calculadora(request):
universidades = Universidad.objects.all()
carreras = Carrera.objects.all()
form = InteresadosForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    print form.cleaned_data
    email = form_data.get("email")
    obj = PersonasInteresadas(email=email)
print universidades
print carreras
#if universidades.is_valid():
#   print universidades.cleaned_data
contexto = {"universidades":universidades,
            "carreras":carreras,
            "form":form
            }
return render(request,"index.html", contexto)
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` first?

Comment: Yes, always run makemigrations

Comment: Did you add your app into `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: yes, it was added.

Comment: `makemigrations` is insufficient. That just creates the migration files; you will need to run them to create the database tables. The complete process would be 1) run `makemigrations` on your local machine. 2) commit the resulting migrations to git, 3) push to heroku, and 4) execute `heroku run python manage.py migrate`